# amount of divs relative to length of list

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a web project, and although I'm pretty familiar with HTML & CSS, I'm new to JavaScript. Here's my current setup:

```js
//in full setup, the var is stored as a seperate file, loaded first, to make the JSON more convenient to edit
var jsonList = 
{
    "first": {
        "Friendly": "Nest Mini (2nd gen)",
        "Model": "Google Nest Mini (2nd Generation)",
        "Manufacturer": "Google",
        "Type": "speaker",
        "Tech": [
            "wifi"
        ],
        "Software": [
            "Google Home"
        ]
    }
};

document.getElementById("friendly").innerHTML = jsonList.first.Friendly;
document.getElementById("model").innerHTML = jsonList.first.Model;
document.getElementById("manufacturer").innerHTML = jsonList.first.Manufacturer;
document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = jsonList.first.Type;
document.getElementById("tech").innerHTML = jsonList.first.Tech;
document.getElementById("software").innerHTML = jsonList.first.Software;
```

```css
#card {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    vertical-align:top;
    border-radius:25px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #0000002a, 0 6px 20px 0 #0000002a;
    position:relative;
    line-height:8px;
    height:150px;
    padding-left:150px /* normally an icon goes to the left */
}

#friendly {
    font-size:40px;
    padding-top:30px;
    line-height:0px
}
#model {
    opacity:40%;
    line-height:0px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
}
#type,#tech,#software {
    display:inline
}
```

```html
    <div id="card">
        <p id="friendly"></p>
        <p id="model"></p>
        <p>Made by <span id="manufacturer"></span></p>
        <p id="type"></p>
        <p id="tech"></p> 
        <p id="software"></p>
    </div>
```

What I would like to do, is to be able to add a "second", "third", etc and have a relative amount of divs be made automatically. So for instance, if I had 3 entries in the JSON, I'd have 3 `<div id="code">`. (ideally, the values would be named "0001", "0002" and so forth, but that seems to introduce new issues beyond the scope of this.)

Anyways, I'm wondering what the best way would be to go about this. When I looked into it, I saw you could append to lists in JS, and so maybe that would be the route to take, but I'm not sure. Hopefully someone with more experience in web technologies can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a perfect candidate for the html `<template>` element.
Note that repeated IDs aren't legal html. I've changed the IDs to Classes to avoid that problem.

I've also slightly massaged the format of the JSON data. I've stored the individual items into an array. It seems a better idea than named attributes like "first", "second", "last" etc. You assume the first item in the array is first and the next second, etc...

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

var jsonListItems = 
[
            {
                "Friendly": "Nest Mini (2nd gen)",
                "Model": "Google Nest Mini (2nd Generation)",
                "Manufacturer": "Google",
                "Type": "speaker",
                "Tech": ["wifi"],
                "Software": ["Google Home"]
            },
            {
                "Friendly": "Nest Max (32nd gen)",
                "Model": "Google Nest Max (0x20 nd Generation)",
                "Manufacturer": "Goggle",
                "Type": "siren",
                "Tech": ["blue-toof"],
                "Software": ["Google Ghetto blastah"]
            }
];

function onLoaded(event)
{
    jsonListItems.forEach( item => document.body.appendChild(makeItemDisplay(item)) );
    
    function makeItemDisplay(data)
    {
        let src = document.getElementById('cardTemplate');
        let newCard = src.content.cloneNode(true);
        
        newCard.querySelector('.friendly').textContent = data.Friendly;
        newCard.querySelector('.model').textContent = data.Model;
        newCard.querySelector('.manufacturer').textContent = data.Manufacturer;
        
        newCard.querySelector('.type').textContent = data.Type;
        newCard.querySelector('.tech').textContent = data.Tech;
        newCard.querySelector('.software').textContent = data.Software;
        
        return newCard;
    }
}
```

```css
.card {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    vertical-align:top;
    border-radius:25px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #0000002a, 0 6px 20px 0 #0000002a;
    position:relative;
    line-height:8px;
    height:150px;
    padding-left:150px /* normally an icon goes to the left */
}
```

```html
<template id='cardTemplate'>
<div class="card">
        <p class="friendly"></p>
        <p class="model"></p>
        <p>Made by <span class="manufacturer"></span></p>
        <p class="type"></p>
        <p class="tech"></p> 
        <p class="software"></p>
</div>  
</template>
```